# Custom Calculated Column to sort dates based on entry date

Tags: list, list-view, custom-list, calculated-column, calculated-column-formula

**Edit:
Hi, I know it has been a while since this was answered but I am having some issues with this formula. Since the start of the year it is giving me two different week numbers for each week. This is what my columns look like right now,

```
ByWeek:2017_01
WeekStart    WeekEnd    EntryDate
1/6/2017     1/13/2016  1/13/2017
ByWeek:2017_02
WeekStart    WeekEnd    EntryDate
1/13/2017    1/20/2016  1/20/2017
ByWeek:2017_1
WeekStart    WeekEnd    EntryDate
1/6/2017     1/13/2016  1/17/2017
ByWeek:2017_2
WeekStart    WeekEnd    EntryDate
1/13/2017    1/20/2016  1/23/2017
```

Every WeekNo is being separated into two different weeks, 01 and 1, 02 and 2, etc. and the date ranges are different. Can anyone tell why this would be happening suddenly when this worked fine all last year?

I have a calculated column right now for the purpose of a Weekly Action Report (WAR) that shows entries from a form based on the date the user enters and sorts the entries by week. The issue is our week is not a standard week, it is Wednesday to Wednesday. Here is the formula I have currently:

```
=YEAR(EntryDate)&"_"&IF(INT((EntryDate-DATE(YEAR(EntryDate)
,1,2-WEEKDAY(DATE(YEAR(EntryDate),1,1))))/7)<10,"0","")&INT((EntryDate-DATE(YEAR(EntryDate)
,1,2-WEEKDAY(DATE(YEAR(EntryDate),1,1))))/7)
```

This displays results like this:
ByWeek: 2016_35 (where 35 would be the 35th week of the year). This works functionally, but my team has to be sure to change the entry date to the previous Friday if they are making an entry for Monday-Wednesday of the current week, else the entry will appear in a new field such as 2016_36, which defeats the purpose of sorting the entries by week for the weekly reports.

Additionally, I would like to display the week range for each week instead of the actual week number if possible. Thanks all.

Answer (score 0):

Create another calculated column as WeekNo just to increase the readability of the final formula

```
WeekNo=IF(INT((EntryDate-DATE(YEAR(EntryDate),1,2-WEEKDAY(DATE(YEAR(EntryDate),1,1))))/7)<10,"0","")&INT((EntryDate-DATE(YEAR(EntryDate),1,2-WEEKDAY(DATE(YEAR(EntryDate),1,1))))/7)
```

Then, if the EntryDate is Sunday, Monday or Tuesday or Wednesday actual week number should be WeekNo-1

```
=IF(WEEKDAY(EntryDate)=1,YEAR(EntryDate)&"_"&WeekNo-1,IF(WEEKDAY(EntryDate)=2,YEAR(EntryDate)&"_"&WeekNo-1,IF(WEEKDAY(EntryDate)=3,YEAR(EntryDate)&"_"&WeekNo-1,IF(WEEKDAY(EntryDate)=4,YEAR(EntryDate)&"_"&WeekNo-1,YEAR(EntryDate)&"_"&WeekNo))))
```

Comment: where should I enter the 2nd formula, in the WeekNo column or the ByWeek column I have?

Comment: In the ByWeek column.

Comment: Ok, I added the WeekNo column, which works fine. I added an entry with yesterday's date and it appeared in the current reporting week which is exactly what I needed. Only thing left would be to make the reporting date more readable if that's possible.

Comment: Assume you need to find Week Start Date and End Date based on the entry date and week starts on Wednesday

Create 2  Date Only calculated columns as WeekStartDate and WeekEndDate. Then formulas would be

WeekStartDate =DATE(YEAR(EntryDate),1,1)+INT(RIGHT(ByWeek,LEN(ByWeek)-INT(FIND("_",ByWeek))))*7-2

WeekEndDate =WeekStartDate+7

Comment: Hi, I know it has been a while since this was answered but I am having some issues with this formula and I hope you can help. Since the start of the year it is giving me two different week numbers for each week. This is what my columns look like right now,
ByWeek:2017_01
WeekStart    WeekEnd    EntryDate
1/6/2017     1/13/2016  1/13/2017
ByWeek:2017_02
WeekStart    WeekEnd    EntryDate
1/13/2017    1/20/2016  1/20/2017
ByWeek:2017_1
WeekStart    WeekEnd    EntryDate
1/6/2017     1/13/2016  1/17/2017
ByWeek:2017_2
WeekStart    WeekEnd    EntryDate
1/13/2017    1/20/2016  1/23/2017

Comment: WeekNo Formula is appending a "0" if the WeekNo is less than 10. This is causing a formatting issue if EntryDate is Sunday, Monday or Tuesday or Wednesday. So if we update the WeekNo formula to not to append the "0", ByWeek column should display consistent values like 2017_1, 2017_2..  So, try updating WeekNo Formula to WeekNo=INT((EntryDate-DATE(YEAR(EntryDate),1,2-WEEKDAY(DATE(YEAR(EntryDate),1,1))))/7)

Comment: So that works for the grouping issue, but I'm still having the issue of the dates not grouping correctly. For example, currently WeekNo 4 is showing as starting on 1/27/2017, ending on 2/3/2016, but it has entry dates showing in the group from 2/7/2017. Do you know what could be causing the dates to be off like that?

Answer (score 0):

It appears that the formula for the WeekNo you provided in the question has some issue. All other formulas are depending on this formula. I have changed the formulas to resolve the issue. Please try below formulas.

```
WeekNo =INT((EntryDate-DATE(YEAR(EntryDate),1,1)+7-WEEKDAY(EntryDate,1))/7)+1

WeekEnd =DATE(YEAR(EntryDate),1,1)+WeekNo*7-1

WeekStart =WeekEnd-6

ByWeek =IF(AND(WeekNo=1,WEEKDAY(EntryDate)<5),YEAR(EntryDate)-1&"_"&INT((EntryDate-INT(WEEKDAY(EntryDate))-DATE(YEAR(EntryDate-INT(WEEKDAY(EntryDate))),1,1)+7-WEEKDAY(EntryDate-INT(WEEKDAY(EntryDate)),1))/7)+1,IF(WEEKDAY(EntryDate)<5,YEAR(EntryDate)&"_"&WeekNo-1,YEAR(EntryDate)&"_"&WeekNo))
```

I have assumed week number 1 is starting from January 1st of each year.

Comment: The ByWeek formula is giving me a syntax error, but the other formulas went in fine. The other thing is our reporting period is from Tuesday to Tuesday, rather than Monday-Friday. Thanks for all your help!